# Find the interval of convergence for $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}$.

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

Find the interval of convergence for $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}$.

I tried using the ratio test to find the radius of convergence. 
\begin{align}
\lim_{k\to\infty}\dfrac{\left|\frac{x^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}\right|}{\left|\frac{x^k}{k!}\right|} &= \lim_{k\to\infty}\left|\dfrac{x}{k+1}\right| =0
\end{align}
Doesn't this tell us that we can choose any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ because $\lim_{k\to\infty}\left|\dfrac{x}{k+1}\right| =0$ for any $x$?

Comment: Indeed, that series converges everywhere on $\mathbb{R}$ (it has an infinite radius of convergence).

Comment: One can even [calculate the limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function#Formal_definition).

Comment: The expansion of $e^x = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^k / k!$ converges for all $x \in {\mathbb R}$.